# Settling a margin left to half of the screen width

Tags: javascript, margin

I'm doing a project for school and I need to set the margin of this button to half of the screen width. It isn't working currently:

```
document.getElementById("listStyle").style.marginLeft = ((screen.width) / 2) = "px";
```

The id of the button is listStyle.

Thanks!

Comment: `+ 'px'`  insteadof `= 'px'`

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("listStyle").style.marginLeft = ((screen.width) / 2) **=** "px";
```

need + instead of =